# Angularjs variable undefined outside of function

Tags: angularjs, resources, undefined

Whenever I call the cardslength variable or just cards.length, I get undefined outside of the function. Does this mean I need to use $scope? I am using angular 1.0.5 btw because this is part of a tutorial I am following and I needed to use that version.

This is my code:

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function ($resource, $q) {
var resource = $resource('/data/event/:id', {id: '@id'});


//////////////////////This is the part that doesn't seem to be working//////////
var cardslength
var cards = resource.query(function() {
        cardslength = cards.length;
        });
        console.log(cardslength);
        console.log(cards.length);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


return {
    getEvent: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        resource.get({id: 1},
            function (event) {
                deferred.resolve(event);
            },
            function (response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    },
    save: function(event) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        event.id = 1234;
        resource.save(event,
            function(response) { deferred.resolve(response);},
            function(response) { deferred.reject(response);}
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

Comment: That means resource.query() does not return anything, or your callback is execute before something is returned, overall bad service implementation

Comment: Inside the function it works fine

Comment: Before the function its just defined but has undefined, logical, where else do you access it and it doesn't work? also remember `cardslength ` will have a value only when query() finishes execution

Comment: console.log(cardslength);
console.log(cards.length);

Are both not working when I request them after the function but they work when I put them inside of the resource.query function

Comment: Yes in that case its still undefined because .query() did not finish execution, so your console.log() is excuted before query() finishes.

Comment: I got it to work with settimeout, but I am still looking for the correct way to do this.

Comment: Correct way is to use it only when query() finishes execution. No other way

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log` is executed before the `.query()` finishes. In order to avoid this, try as follows:

```
var cards = resource.query(function() {
    cardslength = cards.length;
}).then(function(){
    console.log(cardslength);
    console.log(cards.length);
});
```

Comment: That also gets me undefined.

Comment: Actually, it's not working because you are using Angular 1.0.5. The above answer is only working with Angular 1.1.3 and later.

Comment: Acteally I just found out that in the latest Angularjs you need to use .$promise.then(){};